# Ajax call returns parsererror

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have a Controller with the Action Like This

```
public ActionResult UpdateCompanyInfo(Parameter parameter)
{
   bool result = false;
   if(ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      bla bla bla
   }

   return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I also have a javascript function:

```
function blabla(){
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "What Ever",
        async: false,
        data: JSON.stringify(jsonObject),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (succeed) {
            if (succeed) {
                // Some Code
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            //Some Other Code
        }
    });

}
```

the javascript function calls properly and it hits Action method with the parameter (No problem yet!).
but when the Action method returns `bool` object using `Json` function, it hits the javascript error function response with the following parameters:

```
readyState   4
responseText "true"
status       200
statusText   "parsererror"
jQuery15101815967692459196_1384707824272 was not called
```

I also tried
`return Json(new { result }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` and
`return Json(new {succeed = result }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` and
`return Json(new {succeed = result.ToString() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`
but they did not work too.
in addition i have an exactly the same function in another controller which calls another same javascript function but it works properly. I don't know what's wrong with it. am i missing something?

----------- EDIT --------------
I don't know why! but when i remove the `dataType: 'json',` from the Ajax call, and put `return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` in action method, it works properly. could someone explain it to my "why?"

Comment: `"true"` is not valid JSON, you should return something like `{"response": "true"}`

Comment: @adeneo I already tried that. it did not work: `return Json(new { result }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` and `return Json(new {succeed = result }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` and `return Json(new {succeed = result.ToString() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: @adeneo so why my another same second approach works fine with `return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` i have mentioned it in the bottom of the Question.

Comment: Maybe you didn't set `dataType: 'json',` ?

Comment: @adeneo please read the edited section of Question. do you have any explanation?

Comment: Sure do, when you use `dataType: 'json'` you're telling jQuery that whatever is coming back from the server should be valid JSON, so jQuery tries to parse that result with `JSON.parse`, but if whatever you return from the server isn't JSON, it fails, creating a parse error, and just sending `"true"` isn't valid JSON, so that fails. On the other hand, if you remove `dataType: 'json'`, jQuery has no expectations, and whatever you return from the server is not parsed at all, and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it seems there is a bug in jquery 1.5.1 and 1.5.0 (which does not exist in previous versions).
In fact when you use `dataType: 'json'` it tries to parse json as a script and you should use `dataType: 'text/json'` instead. see [this link](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8302).

Comment: actualy 'text' without json, but that is the answer!

Answer (score 1):

The data returned from the server might not be of json type. So you can use below two method to overcome.

*Option 1:*
Use `dataType: 'text'` as part of ajax request.

*Option 2:*
Remove the **dataType** from ajax request as it will try to infer it based on the type of the response.

Answer (score 0):

From your response, In controller,  there is no json encoded data,  jsonformat looks like, `{'responseText':'your text here '}`

Answer (score 0):

You are only returning a single value which the JSON parser in JS will not accept. Try this:

```
public ActionResult UpdateCompanyInfo(Parameter parameter)
{
   bool result = false;
   if(ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      bla bla bla
   }

   return Json(new { success = result }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The anonymous object returned by JSON will look like this:

```
[{ "success": true }]
```

Which you can then deal with in your `success` handler, like this:

```
success: function (data) {
    if (data.success) {
        // Some Code
    }
    else {
        // Bad things going down
    }
},
```

Comment: @Roly McCrossan i tried it. it hits the : error function. error parameters not changed except `responseText "{"success":true}"`

Comment: @Roly McCrossan please read the edited section of Question. do you have any explanation?